# How to find a ininite loop in glassfishv3

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

I have s.t. like a infinite loop some where in the code. That place is somehow not called often. So after a couple of hours one of the CPU's on the Linux machine start's running at 100% then after a while another one etc.
Restarting the server solves the problem for a while.

How can i find the place where this happens?

I thought about setting the RequestTimeout very small. (5 min) Would I get a proper error message in the log that tells me what's wrong.

top with command "H"

**16639 java      20   0 9836m 2.6g  17m R  100 16.5  39:55.33 java**
18059 java      20   0 2745m 2.3g  17m S    2 14.5   0:00.92 java
16591 java      20   0 9836m 2.6g  17m S    1 16.5   0:15.97 java
 5307 java      20   0 8945m 4.6g 3864 S    1 29.1 746:47.67 java

and then:
jstack -J-d64 16639

But I get:
16639: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
The -F option can be used when the target process is not responding

Must I start s.t. on the machine before?

Nice article about how to search for the hotspot:

http://code.nomad-labs.com/2010/11/18/identifying-which-java-thread-is-consuming-most-cpu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have privileges in the machine you can execute `jstack`.

`jstack` execute a thread dump on the application. From there you can check which thread is in an infinite loop.

[Jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html) is bundled with the `jdk`.

Another way is to check `top` command (*nix) and enable the thread view. From there you can check which thread is consuming the cpu. Then with `jstack` you can see a `nid` which is the hexadecimal value of the thread.

You can use `jps` to obtain java pid.

Comment: That was not too bad but i cannot get any data out of jstack. Any idea why?

Comment: See this articel : http://code.nomad-labs.com/2010/11/18/identifying-which-java-thread-is-consuming-most-cpu/